# IBOutlet creates double references

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, iboutlet

When I try to create an IBOutlet in XCode by CTRL+Drag the outlet to the viewcontroller, two identical references are created. It casues the view to disappear unexpectedly. Has anyone had this problem before?

[image]

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Latest version of XCode, 11